# How to create a 2D mesh and obtain all the coordinates and connectivity

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I know this is a really amateur question, but I´m kind of new in here. Though I´ve been trying for the last few days I simply cannot convert a set of points (well actually a region) to a mesh. But also, after getting the mesh I need to obtain the coordinates and connectivity of all the elements, can that be done with a function?
The region is this on

```
{{15, 0}, {35, 0}, {35, 25}, {50, 25}, {50, 45}, {40, 45}, {40, 
  65}, {35, 70}, {15, 70}, {10, 65}, {10, 45}, {0, 45}, {0, 25}, {15, 
  25}}
```

Any help I could get woud be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: So I started with the Needs[NDsolve`FEM`] , ToElementMesh[DiscretizeGraphics] and my set of points, I got a decent mesh actually but after that using meshnodes or meshtopology wouldn´t work

Comment: Would it help to work with a graph for connectivity? `Graph[DirectedEdge[points[[#, 1]], points[[#, 2]]] & /@Range[Length[points]]]`

Answer (score 8):

The documentation of [ToElementMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) has many examples.

For your specific data sett:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{15, 0}, {35, 0}, {35, 25}, {50, 25}, {50, 
      45}, {40, 45}, {40, 65}, {35, 70}, {15, 70}, {10, 65}, {10, 
      45}, {0, 45}, {0, 25}, {15, 25}}
   ];

mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
mesh["Coordinates"]

{{15., 0.}, {35., 0.}, {35., 25.}, {50., 25.}, {50., 
  45.}, {40., 45.}, {40., 65.}, {35., 70.}, {15., 70.}, {10., 
  65.}, {10., 45.}, {0., 45.}, {0., 25.}, {15., 25.}}

mesh["MeshElements"]

{TriangleElement[{{13, 1, 14}, {14, 1, 2}, {13, 14, 11}, {12, 11, 
    10}, {11, 12, 13}, {9, 10, 11}, {9, 11, 6}, {11, 14, 3}, {2, 4, 
    3}, {3, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 14}, {8, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 6}, {5, 7, 6}, {6, 4,
     5}, {6, 11, 3}}]}
```